Error in geom_textpath with coord_curvedpolar when single row data.frame is used
I have a plot function with many layers that fails with an error depending
on the input dataset.
This dataset (~2000 rows) is used to compute a seasons data.frame that
is used in some layers of the plot. It usually has several rows as the input
dataset contains many dates.
When the input dataset is filtered (for example the first year has only
a few months available), then the seasons data.frame contains only one row.
After some exploration, I could reduce the whole issue to the following
code:
library(ggplot2)
library(geomtextpath)


seasons_1 <- data.frame(name = c("summer", "winter"),
                        start = as.Date(c("2019-12-01", "2019-06-01")),
                        end = as.Date(c("2019-12-31", "2019-08-31")))


seasons_2 <- data.frame(name = "summer",
                        start = as.Date("2019-12-01"),
                        end = as.Date("2019-12-31"))

# -- plot
helper <- function(x)
  ggplot(x) +
  
  # -- winters & summers text
  geom_textpath(
    aes(
      x = end - (end - start)/2,
      label = name),
    y = 1,
  ) +
  
  # -- make it polar
  coord_curvedpolar()


print(helper(seasons_1))
print(helper(seasons_2))


seasons_1 will output a plot
seasons_2 will throw the following error:
Error in `geom_textpath()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `$<-.data.frame`:
! le tableau de remplacement a 1 lignes, le tableau remplacé en a 0
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Update
As commented by @AllanCameron, I tried to ajust single row dataframe to get 2 rows. I'm putting it in this update for the record because the workaround needs a bit of tuning: depending on the offset and/or how it overlaps or not, you may face other error messages.
# -- Adding a 2nd row with no offset
seasons_3 <- data.frame(name = c("summer", " "),
                        start = as.Date(c("2019-12-01", "2019-12-01")),
                        end = as.Date(c("2019-12-31", "2019-12-31")))

print(helper(seasons_3))

Erreur dans check.length(gparname) :
   l élément 'fontsize' de 'gpar' doit être de longueur unitaire

# (the 'fontsize' element of 'gpar' must be of unit length)

# -- Adding a 2nd row with very small offset
seasons_3 <- data.frame(name = c("summer", " "),
                        start = as.Date(c("2019-12-01", "2019-12-02")),
                        end = as.Date(c("2019-12-31", "2019-12-31")))

print(helper(seasons_3))

Erreur dans seq.default(-wid/2, wid/2, len = 1000) :
   'from' doit être un nombre fini

# ('from' must be a finite number)

# -- Adding a 2nd row with small offset
seasons_4 <- data.frame(name = c("summer", " "),
                        start = as.Date(c("2019-12-01", "2019-12-05")),
                        end = as.Date(c("2019-12-31", "2019-12-31")))

print(helper(seasons_3))

The last one will work :)
I would recommend to check your own limit cases if you run into same issue.

Thanks for making a clear and minimal reproducible example. This looks like a bug to me, so I recommend reporting it (with this example) to https://github.com/AllanCameron/geomtextpath/issues

The issue also occurs with coord_polar. The problem is with geom_textpath itself. Ideally, textpaths should run along a path, but we did add the option of "pointlike" text paths, as in your example, to allow curving in non-linear co-ordinate systems. When there is only a single value on the x axis, the ggplot coord_munch function isn't given enough information to calculate the radial distance around which the path should curve. This is probably fixable, but in the meantime a workaround would be to conditionally adjust 1 row data frames to 2-row data frames with a small x offset.

Thanks for the explanation @AllanCameron!

Thanks a lot @AllanCameron for the clear explanation! I ran into a few issues to tune the workaround (that I put in the question as an update) but I could solve the problem.
